# Does a sharepoint administrator have to be a server administrator?

Tags: powershell

Specifically, I am looking at giving a user the permissions to run PowerShell commands, on a SharePoint 2013 server, remotely from their PC.

The user was a sharepoint administrator on sharepoint 2010 and had administrator rights on the windows 2008 server.  Now we are moving to windows 2012 and sharepoint 2013 and the powers-that-be want to limit the amount of users with admin rights to the servers as we do so.  That's fair enough but they don't know how to do it for sharepoint and have given me the task - and I know nothing about sharepoint.  So, any help would be appreciated - even just letting me know where to go to find the information I need.  I have googled but everything I find seems to assume a certain level of knowledge on sharepoint.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to have three things in order to be able to access and run the SharePoint snapin of Powershell.

> •You must have membership in the **securityadmin** fixed server role on
>   the SQL Server instance
>
> •You must have membership in the **db_owner** fixed database role on all
>   databases that are to be updated.
>
> •You must be a member of the **Administrators** group on the server on
>   which you are running the Windows PowerShell cmdlet.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx#section3

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I had already looked at that page but, immediately before the part you have quoted, it says:- "Before you can use the Add-SPShellAdmin cmdlet to grant permissions for users to run SharePoint 2013 cmdlets, verify that you meet all of the following minimum requirements".  To me that is saying that you need to have these things to be able to grant others the ability to run cmdlets, not that the person running the cmdlets has to have those things.  Maybe I am reading it wrong.